# FullCalendar Scheduler - Displaying multiple agendaDays for multiple items in "resources" object?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have a requirement, wherein, I wish to split a vertical resource view, even more vertically.

For example, please consider the example given [here](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.9.1/demos/vertical-resource-view.html).
In this example, there are 4 columns, viz. Rooms "A" to "D", for a single day.

[image]

.

What I wish to have is 4 sets of "single day rows", one below the other, with a header of the Room title for each set.
For example:

```
[..................Header Info ................]
[.    (including Day Title and filters).       ]
[..............................................]
[................... Room A ...................]
[12 AM: .......................................]



[11 PM: .......................................]
[..............................................]


[................... Room  B...................]
[12 AM: .......................................]


[11 PM: .......................................]
[..............................................]
```

and so on..

I tried looking for any kind of online documentation of the same, but was unable to find anything.

Comment: So basically you want the rooms vertically underneath each other, instead of side-by-side? Each with its own time grid? Might I ask why? That will produce a _very_ long vertical column. Doesn't sound very user-friendly. There's also no option in fullCalendar / Scheduler to achieve it unfortunately. You'd have to write your own custom view, but that's a major hassle, or fake it by having four separate fullCalendar instances vertically underneath each other on the page, each displaying one resource...but then you have to keep them in sync (e.g. when dates change) which is also a pain

Comment: The main reason for doing this @ADyson, is that I wish to have a responsive FullCalendar. The view posted above is to be made for a standard smartphone. (The decision to switch can be made using viewport metadata)

Comment: fullCalendar just isn't responsive, I'm afraid. It's based on a fixed grid system. The width and height can be varied, but the basic layout stays the same. You'd have to completely re-write the rendering algorithms, I believe. You _might_ be able to do something with a custom view, but I don't know how much flexibility you actually get. More details in the second half of this article: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/